# how to delete history on excel 2007 that shows on windows taskbar

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel-2007, taskbar, file-history

I want to disable showing history of ms excel which is shown in taskbar by clicking right-button of mouse.

[image: showing history by clicking right button of mouse.jpg]

Comment: You can disable it for all programs, I'm not aware of any software specific solution. http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/clear-recent-items-windows-jumplists/

Answer (score 0):

1. Click the File tab.
2. Click Open - Recent.
3. Right-click any location in the Recent Places list
   and select "Clear unpinned places".
4. Click Yes to clear all unpinnned places from the list.
   Any pinned places will still appear.